# I want remove extension from download video

Tags: bash, scripts, video, youtube

How can I remove the default extension of my download video with a script.

Thanks for your help.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
read -p "enter URL:" url
read -p "enter title:" title
read -p "enter  extension:" myext
youtube-dl $url --restrict-filenames
```

## download video

```
youtube-dl -o "/home/guillem/Desktop/youtube/Videos/$titol.$myext" $url
```

## move video to my folder with 2 extension (title.myext.defaultext)

Answer (score 0):

[Searching Ubuntu's packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rename&searchon=names&suite=cosmic&section=all) would find the [`rename`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/rename) utility, it's man page has this as it's first example:

> For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the extension, you might say
>
> ```
> rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Rename sounds like the ideal utility, but if you need more flexibility, you can use a oneliner to do it:

For example, to get rid of the extension and move it to $DIR (run from the dir where the files are)

`ls *.bak | sed 's/\.bak$//' | xargs -I % mv %.bak $DIR/%`

- `ls *.bak` - find all files ending in `.bak`
- `sed 's/\.bak$//'` - remove `.bak`
- `xargs -I %` - run the next command per input, putting the input wherever there is a `%`
- `mv %.bak $DIR/%` - move the original file (by readding the extension) to $DIR without the extension